# route request to a different controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller that has read function and handles urls like this

```
-> /{id}/EnumElement
class FirstController {
    Object read(@PathVariable UUID id, @PathVariable EnumeratedEntity value, 
        HttpServletRequest request)
}
```

I want to add the second controller that would handle only a single request

```
class SecondController {
    -> /{id}/metadata
    Object meta(@PathVariable UUID id, HttpServletRequest request)
}
```

I also have a controller advice that supposed to handle EnumeratedEntity values

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class DefaultControllerAdvice {
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(EnumeratedEntity.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
    @Override
    public void setAsText(final String text) {
        try {
            setValue(EnumeratedEntity.valueOf(text));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new UnknownResourceException("The requested resource is not supported", e);
        }
    }
    });
}
```

The problem is that each time I request `/metadata` the advicer is trying to get the value of metadata (that does not exist) and throws an error. Also it seems like it takes first controller as a priority or something.

Is there a way to route `/metadata` request to a second controller and ignore advicer altogether?

Answer (score 0):

After some search I decided to go with this solution for the first controller

```
@GetMapping(/{id}/{enumElement:^(?!metadata).*})
Object read(@PathVariable UUID id, @PathVariable EnumeratedEntity value, 
    HttpServletRequest request)
```